# Unable to implement Explicit wait

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to add explicit wait in scripting but I am getting the following error

> "The type com.google.common.base.Function cannot be resolved. It is
>   indirectly referenced from required .class files"

My code

```
WebElement okButton;
okButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@id='buttonResolveResultOk']")));
```

Comment: who is `wait` in your code? you need a `WebDriverWait` there

Comment: You are missing one of selenium libraries. Do you use maven/gradle?

Comment: Yes I am using Maven ,I added selenium using <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: I am not sure which jar file is missing , kindly let me know if you have faced this issue earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated my guava to latest which helped me to solve this issue

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>21.0</version>
</dependency>
```